# I want get message with their associate guard user and client names laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two Auth guard admin and client. I want save their conversation into Message table with their ids and type like below.

> **table message**

```
+----+---------+--------------+--------+
| id | message | messenger_id |  Type  |
+----+---------+--------------+--------+
| 1  | hello   |           1  | client |
| 2  | hi      |           1  | admin  |
+----+---------+--------------+--------+
```

> **table admin**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | abc  |
+----+------+
```

> **table client**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | cde  |
+----+------+
```

**Expected result like**

cde : hello

abc: hi

Comment: What did you try? Show what have you done, share your code where you are trying to save data as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change **field Name of table Message ** from **messenger_id ,Type** to **'messagable_id' ,'messagable_type'** Then this eloquent query give me expected result

Message::with('messagable')->get();

cde : hello

abc: hi

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you're after a [Polymorphic Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)

Something like this should give you a rough idea of what you'd need.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the owning messagable model.
     */
    public function messagable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Admin extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the admin message.
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Message', 'messagable');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user image.
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Message', 'messagable');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it is useful code need polymorphic-relationships, however i want to get all messages with their name by their id and type - client , admin accordingly  my  see my query

Comment: see my query  `Message::all();`  or  `Message::with('messagable')->get();` not get names of messenger